# Webrtc connectivity test - unknown API key

Tags: web, webrtc, connectivity

When we try to run the UDP and Bandwidth tests from the given sample code, it tries to hit a Google API service URL (using ajax call) which looks like "https://networktraversal.googleapis.com/v1alpha/iceconfig?key=". 
This service URL needs to be appended with an API_KEY before making an ajax call.

When I tried to run this example https://test.webrtc.org/ 
It is appending API_KEY to the Base_URL and making an ajax call (POST call) to get some data.
The tests are initiated based on the response data.

Base_URL: "https://networktraversal.googleapis.com/v1alpha/iceconfig?key="
API_KEY: "AIzaSyDX4ctY_VWUm7lDdO6i_-bx7J-CDkxS16I"
Service URL looks like this: "https://networktraversal.googleapis.com/v1alpha/iceconfig?key=AIzaSyDX4ctY_VWUm7lDdO6i_-bx7J-CDkxS16I"

This service gives the response.

All the tests like UDP, Bandwith etc are performed based on the "response.iceServers" Array.

When I tried to hit this service using the same API_KEY from the example, it is throwing an error "Invalid API_KEY from the request URL." So here to access this data we need to have an API_KEY.

Can someone please tell me what API_KEY is this and which one should I use??

Regards.

Comment: How to obtain this key?